# pset2 - Caesar. Outputs match but fails check50

Tags: c, cs50

Sorry, I know this has been asked before but I have read all the answers and nothing works! Please help.
When I check acutal and expected outputs, they match, but in check50 It gives an error message.
Here is the link for check50 results: https://submit.cs50.io/check50/6d939efb8a55e3fadec1c60952311f6198cd0eb0

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char crypt(int k,char w)
{
    if ('a'<= w && w <='z')
    {
        return (((w-'a')+ k)%26+'a');
    }
    else if ('A' <= w && w <= 'Z')
    {
        return (((w -'A') + k) % 26 + 'A');
    }
    else
    {
        return (w);
    }
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //input check
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int lngg = strlen(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < lngg; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1])%26;
    //input

    string plain = get_string("plaintext:  ");

    //crpypt starts

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    int lng = strlen(plain)+1;
    for (int a = 0; a < lng ;a++)
    {
        printf("%c", crypt(key, plain[a]));
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Hi, When I look expected and actual outputs, everything seems perfect but it errors

Comment: Why are you adding 1 here? `int lng = strlen(plain)+1;`

Comment: Aside: `atoi(argv[1])%26` better as `(atoi(argv[1])%26 + 26)%26` to cope with negative `atoi(argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are also printing the terminating null character to standard output using `printf`. This character is not printable, so you cannot see it, but `check50` does detect it and therefore reports that your program failed.

The loop

```
for(int a=0; a<lng ;a++)
{
    printf("%c",crypt(key,plain[a]));
}
```

will run for `strlen(plain)+1` iterations, because that is the value to which you set the variable `lng`.

You should instead set the value of `lng` to `strlen(plain)`, in order to prevent the terminating null character from being printed.

Answer (score 0):

@w is correct.

Also, code can avoid 2 passes down the string and do only 1.

```
// int lng = strlen(plain)+1;
// for (int a = 0; a < lng ;a++)

for (int a = 0; plain[a] != '\0'; a++)
```